# Need to Reset Windows 10 Dual Boot (no recovery environement found)

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, bcdedit

I had a dual boot configuration on my old X58 platform. The setup was an up to date Windows 10 partition and a Windows 1809 partion. Both OS's were on the same SSD which had the same system reserved boot partion as a result

I have now moved to a new Z490 platform and cloned my SATA 3 SSD to my new NVME along with it. seeing as its a new platform, I decided to "fresh install" by reseting both partions from within Windows. However I can only do it for my up to date partition: Windows 10 1909. The Windows 1809 partition gives me "Could not find the recovery environement".

I tried "reagentc /enable" but it told me: "REAGENTC.EXE: Unable to update Boot Configuration Data"

So 2 questions then:
Is there a way to create a recovery environment parmanently in Windows 1809 partion so that I won't need an external recovery media just like my Windows 1909 partition?
If not, How can I reset the 1809 partition and not mess up the boot configuration?

OR do I need to reinstall Windows in both partitions and if so, how do I give each one it's own recovery environment

Comment: "How can I reset the 1809 partition and not mess up the boot configuration?" - You can try and download a 1809 ISO and reinstall Windows 10 1809 from within Windows.  However, I suspect you will run into the same error, you don't exactly have a standard configuration.  **Yes;** I understand you don't want to be told that is a potential solution but that is indeed and more likely the only solution to the problem you describe.

Comment: @Ramhound Lol no I actual am open to ideas. Thats why I left those two ending questions. I don't mind redoing both installations if it can be reconfigured to where each installation has its own recovery environment